# not Able to add elements to an ArrayList

Tags: java

i'm still a beginner in java , i am trying to make a pacman game so i tried to make grid to let monesters follow the player , so i made a list called nieghbours contains all the nieghbouring squares to the current square of the monester but when i had a problem first when adding squares to the nieghbours Array list :

- i have a method called chase to update the x,y of the monester before rendering
- i have a method called findNieghbours called in the chase method to find the nieghbours of the current square of the monester .

but an error apear that the nieghbours ArrayList is empty ( has size of 0 )  .

```
public ArrayList<Square> findNieghbours(){
     ArrayList<Square> nieghbours=new ArrayList();
     int currentX=current.getX();
     int currentY=current.getY();

     if(currentX<29&&!grid.get(currentY/30).get(currentX/30+1).isWall()){
       nieghbours.add(grid.get(currentX/30+1).get(currentY/30));
     }
     if(currentX>0&&!grid.get(currentY/30).get(currentX/30-1).isWall()){
        nieghbours.add(grid.get(currentX/30-1).get(currentY/30));
     }
     if(currentY<29&&!grid.get(currentY/30+1).get(currentX/30).isWall()){
        nieghbours.add(grid.get(currentX/30).get(currentY/30+1));
     }
     if(currentY>0&&!grid.get(currentY/30-1).get(currentX/30).isWall()){
       nieghbours.add(grid.get(currentX/30).get(currentY/30-1));
     }

     return nieghbours;
```

```
public void Chase(Square chasedSquare){
    ArrayList<Square> nieghbours=findNieghbours();

    Square lowest=nieghbours.get(0);   

     for(Square square : nieghbours){
       if((square.getX()-chasedSquare.getX()) * (square.getX()-chasedSquare.getX()) + ( square.getY()-chasedSquare.getY()) * ( square.getY()-chasedSquare.getY()) < (lowest.getX()-chasedSquare.getX()) * (lowest.getX()-chasedSquare.getX()) + (lowest.getY()-chasedSquare.getY()) * lowest.getY()-chasedSquare.getY()){

           lowest=square;
       }

     }
     current=lowest;
 }
```

the error apears at this line in chase method :

```
Square lowest=nieghbours.get(0);
```

he said it is empty has size 0

but when i change the third condition to :

```
if(currentY/30<29&&!grid.get(currentX/30+1).get(currentY/30+1).isWall()){
        nieghbours.add(grid.get(currentX/30).get(currentY/30+1));
     }
```

it works but not as i want ( in each corner it jumps in two steps to become on the the right of the player )

Comment: If it's empty, that must mean that every condition in `findNeighbors` is false. Have you done any debugging to find out why that is? Also, just an FYI, neighbors is spelled with "ei", not "ie".

Comment: Do you know it has added elements to the neighbors? Whenever it adds to neighbor print it in console.

Comment: Were none of the conditions true in findNeighbors() so it was never populated with any values, so it is true that it's empty? Have you stepped through the lines in findNeighbors() to see it it does what you expect?

Comment: it as working but in the third condition there was a mistake ( it was both current x and y add to one ) so it was moving in a bad way i changed it , then the problem appeared

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the grid is size 30 by 30. Is this correct?

Then `currentX/30` and `currentY/30` would be always `0`. Is this what you intended?

Did you mean `currentX%30` and `currentY%30` instead?

If you want to go over to the left side, when hitting the right side, you should use `(currentX+1)%30`.